# How to unbrick my smartphone

Tags: unbricking

I rooted my android 4.4.1 jellybean custom built smartphone so i could delete some malwares/adwares that installed themselves as system apps. Now i guess i got too "over-excited" deleting the malware/adware apps, that i mistakenly deleted a clean system app. Now my phone doesn't pass the boot stage and hangs after playing the intro animation. I hope you guys can help me since i didn't totally wipe off everything. Plus the phone is exactly like Google Nexus 5X.

Comment: according to http://rootmyandroid.org/how-to-unbrick-your-android-device-the-ultimate-guide.html/ my device may not be bricked..."Device Gets int a boot loop, and never ends up in the Home screen."-That's my exact problem

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't much that you can do about this... If you have an SD card, back up all the data, and flash a new rom

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, how do i go about flashing a new ROM?, backup has been taken care of. @Rahul2001

Comment: Do you have 4.4.1, or Jelly Bean?  4.4 is KitKat, 4.1-4.3 is JB.

Answer (score 0):

To flash a new ROM, you need to install a Custom Recovery such as ClockWork Mod (CWM) or Team Win Recovery Project (TWRP). These are what will allow you to flash back to a stock ROM- which you said above was 4.4.1 jellybean. That is actually an issue, because jellybean is 4.3, and kitkat is 4.4.1. Just make sure you get the right one, and you should be good (just wanting to bring that to your attention!). I won't go through all of the details, but the gist of the process is: install your Custom Recovery first, then get the stock ROM onto your SD card (Plug into computer and drag/drop zip into phones internal storage). After that, boot into Recovery mode (which will launch the Custom Recovery you installed earlier) on your phone, find the zip and mount it. I won't go too in depth because there are some great articles that explain it way better than I could even try, but here's a start:

Custom Recovery:
http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-install-a-custom-recovery-to-an-android-phone-device/

Flashing stock rom:
http://lifehacker.com/how-to-flash-a-rom-to-your-android-phone-30885281

Comment: And sorry I couldn't just reply to the comments above, I'm a Overflow newb and can't reply to comments until I reach 50 rep, but I really wanted to help!

Comment: Posting this as an answer is the right thing to do, since it's an answer!

Comment: Thanks! I just wasn't sure if I'd get reprimanded since it wasn't a direct answer to his question, but rather his comment above. Better safe than sorry I suppose!

Comment: @steckzt my phone get's in a boot loop, it just plays the boot intro animation and hangs. This means i can't download/install a custom ROM directly from the phone except if there's a way to do it with a laptop or an SD card.

Comment: @DanielTheGeek since you said in your description that the phones exactly like a Nexus 5X, I bet you could get away with using this Nexus Root Toolkit found here: http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/ . Your phone (or at least the 5X) is supported,  It will let you unlock the bootloader, install a custom recovery, and install your rom- all from the program. I've used it 8 or 9 times on my Nexus 7 when I wanted to install a ROM, and it works like a charm!

Comment: @steckzt thanks bro, I'd try it out...even though I'm already thinking of taking it back to the developers for repair.